# Why should a seller of autocall (down out ones) cover gamma risk?

Tags: gamma, payoff

I wonder why sellers of Autocalls should cover the gamma ?

The autocall I'm talking about is of this type :

While the spot never goes below 70 % of the initial value, nothing happens.
If it happens, then the payoff becomes a short put with strike 100 %.

The seller is never at risk, except from a marked to market point of view.

Are we talking about other payoffs ?

Thank you in advance !